# payplan jomsocial auto login and new user activation

Tags: joomla2.5, jomsocial

I am using the payplan and jomsocial for new user registration.

What i need is that new user should automatically logged in after subscription.

I'm using autologin and activate after payment apps and every thing is working fine except new user is not activated after paypal payment.

The user is auto logged even it is not activated.

I have set New user registration setting to 'None'. So user must be activated automatically.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payplans activate after payment app does not activate user automatically.

It just send activation email after payment and user need to click on the activation link send in the email to activate his account.

If you want to activate user account automatically then you should use Quick Registration app for this purpose.
In this app there is an option to activate user account on subscription activation.